# Rails setting data inside a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I have a strange issue setting data inside an active record.. 
When I attempt to set the data inside a method, it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Here's my class

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :returns_policy_refunds, Array
  def reloadRefundOptions!
    @returns_policy_refunds = WebSite.get_refund_options #options array
  end
end
```

Simple as' class eh?

To test serialization I'm just spitting out the data on a screen..

```
-@options.each do |option|
  - option.returns_policy_refunds = ["wtf"] #just to reset things

  <b>BLOCK 1</b>
  = option.reloadRefundOptions!
  = option.returns_policy_refunds
  <br>
  <b>BLOCK 2</b>
  = option.returns_policy_refunds = WebSite.get_refund_options
  = option.returns_policy_refunds
```

Now.. I'd expect to see the same in BLOCK1 as in BLOCK2.. 
The method sets the return policy.. 
What I actually see in the first option.returns_policy_refunds is ["wtf"]

What am I missing?  I must be doing something wrong, but I have no idea what.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave out the `@` in your attribute assignment:

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :returns_policy_refunds, Array
  def reloadRefundOptions!
    self.returns_policy_refunds = WebSite.get_refund_options #options array
  end
end
```

Haven't tried it yet but I would say that `option.returns_policy_refunds` gets the data from the attributes hash defined by ActiveRecord. If you assign a class variable using `@` it's just defined there and may only be accessed with an attribute reader or a direct send.

Comment: No joy.. I tried that b4 but I tried it just now too. I still see WTF in my output.

Comment: I was basing my code on http://tmonrails.wordpress.com/2009/08/05/ruby-setter-and-getter-methods/

Comment: found it.. self.   self. is the answer.